# CTE with multiple UNION ALL, The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

The following code produces: The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

I'm trying to build a list with all parents and childs. ArtikelCEId = 7 is hardcoded as an example.

Running the CTE with only 1 UNION ALL (find parents or childs) works perfectly.

The same kind of coding is described in: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/ctes-multiple-recursive-members

```
create table Article(
    ArtikelCEId int,
    VervangenDoorArtikelCEId int
) 

insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId ) values (1, 2)
insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId ) values (2, null)
insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId )  values (3, null)
insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId ) values (5, 7)
insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId ) values (7, 8)
insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId ) values (8, null)
insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId ) values (9, null)
insert into Article (ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId ) values (10, null)

;                                       
WITH ArtikelCE_CTE(ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId) AS 
( 
  SELECT a.ArtikelCEId, a.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId
  from Article a 
    where a.ArtikelCEId = 7

    /*find parents */
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.ArtikelCEId, b.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId
  FROM ArtikelCE_CTE acteP 
  INNER JOIN Article b 
    ON b.ArtikelCeId = acteP.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId  

  /*find childs */
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.ArtikelCEId, c.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId
  FROM ArtikelCE_CTE acteC 
  INNER JOIN Article c 
    ON c.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId = acteC.ArtikelCeId    
  where c.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId is not null

)


SELECT  ArtikelCeId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId FROM ArtikelCE_CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest splitting your query in two separate CTEs - one for parents, one for children and than joining them at the end. In your idea - you are running into infinite loop because when second union part (for children) is applied to first union part (found parents) you get the original value again.

```
WITH ArtikelCE_CTE_Parents(ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId) AS 
( 
  SELECT a.ArtikelCEId, a.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId
  from Article a 
    where a.ArtikelCEId = 7

    /*find parents */
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.ArtikelCEId, b.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId
  FROM ArtikelCE_CTE_Parents acteP 
  INNER JOIN Article b 
    ON b.ArtikelCeId = acteP.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId  
)
, ArtikelCE_CTE_Children(ArtikelCEId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId) AS 
( 
  SELECT a.ArtikelCEId, a.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId
  from Article a 
    where a.ArtikelCEId = 7

  /*find children */
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.ArtikelCEId, c.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId
  FROM ArtikelCE_CTE_Children acteC 
  INNER JOIN Article c 
    ON c.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId = acteC.ArtikelCeId    
  where c.VervangenDoorArtikelCEId is not null

)
SELECT  ArtikelCeId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId FROM ArtikelCE_CTE_Parents
UNION 
SELECT  ArtikelCeId, VervangenDoorArtikelCEId FROM ArtikelCE_CTE_Children
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to end of query:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

... with any value up to the max allowable of 32767.

Comment: `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` for unlimited recursions if there is a need for more then 32767. But that is not going to help OP as problem here is infinite loop which is exactly why default max is 100.